# Google Pie Chart: Display two values with different colors

Tags: pie-chart

I would like to know how to display in each sector from a google pie chart two values with different colors.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nqkwz33r/ It does it for you, *right?*

Comment: No, I would like to have the same sector with two values and differents colors